# imprime el mismo id de los elementos padre clikeando ah diferente botones JAVASCRIPT Como obetengo los id y clases de los elementos padre

Tags: javascript

```js
function editarDatos(id){
    
var padre=document.getElementById(id).parentNode;
console.log(padre);


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        
        <table border="">px
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Apellidos</th>
                    <th>DNI</th>
                    <th>Correo</th>
                    <th>Editar</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr id="0" class="0">
                    <th id="0" class="0"></th>
                    <th id="0" class="0"></th>
                    <th id="0" class="0">0</th>
                    <th id="0" class="0"></th>
                    <th id="0" class="0"><input type="button" id="btnEditar" onclick="editarDatos(this.id)"
                            value="editar">
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="12345678" class="12345678">
                    <th id="12345678" class="12345678">Yunior</th>
                    <th id="12345678" class="12345678">vergara</th>
                    <th id="12345678" class="12345678">12345678</th>
                    <th id="12345678" class="12345678">operatuin@gmail.com</th>
                    <th id="12345678" class="12345678"><input type="button" id="btnEditar"
                            onclick="editarDatos(this.id)" value="editar"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="12398765" class="12398765">
                    <th id="12398765" class="12398765">Lucia</th>
                    <th id="12398765" class="12398765">jacobo</th>
                    <th id="12398765" class="12398765">12398765</th>
                    <th id="12398765" class="12398765">sadasdas</th>
                    <th id="12398765" class="12398765"><input type="button" id="btnEditar"
                            onclick="editarDatos(this.id)" value="editar"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="32165487" class="32165487">
                    <th id="32165487" class="32165487">Maria</th>
                    <th id="32165487" class="32165487">Hernandez</th>
                    <th id="32165487" class="32165487">32165487</th>
                    <th id="32165487" class="32165487">maria@hotmail.com</th>
                    <th id="32165487" class="32165487"><input type="button" id="btnEditar"
                            onclick="editarDatos(this.id)" value="editar"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="32165498" class="32165498">
                    <th id="32165498" class="32165498">homero</th>
                    <th id="32165498" class="32165498">blas</th>
                    <th id="32165498" class="32165498">32165498</th>
                    <th id="32165498" class="32165498">asdasdasda</th>
                    <th id="32165498" class="32165498"><input type="button" id="btnEditar"
                            onclick="editarDatos(this.id)" value="editar"></th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        
    </div>


    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero de todo no pueden haber ids repetidos en tu html. Si necesitas repetir un identificador, entonces usa las clases, pero los ids deben ser únicos.

Así, tu html:

```
<tbody>
            <tr id="0" class="0">
                <th class="0"></th>
                <th class="0"></th>
                <th class="0">0</th>
                <th class="0"></th>
                <th class="0">
                    <input type="button" onclick="editarDatos(this)"
                        value="editar">
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="12345678" class="12345678">
                <th class="12345678">Yunior</th>
                <th class="12345678">vergara</th>
                <th class="12345678">12345678</th>
                <th class="12345678">operatuin@gmail.com</th>
                <th class="12345678"><input type="button" 
                        onclick="editarDatos(this)" value="editar"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="12398765" class="12398765">
                <th class="12398765">Lucia</th>
                <th class="12398765">jacobo</th>
                <th class="12398765">12398765</th>
                <th class="12398765">sadasdas</th>
                <th class="12398765"><input type="button" 
                        onclick="editarDatos(this)" value="editar"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="32165487" class="32165487">
                <th class="32165487">Maria</th>
                <th class="32165487">Hernandez</th>
                <th class="32165487">32165487</th>
                <th class="32165487">maria@hotmail.com</th>
                <th class="32165487"><input type="button" 
                        onclick="editarDatos(this)" value="editar"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="32165498" class="32165498">
                <th class="32165498">homero</th>
                <th class="32165498">blas</th>
                <th class="32165498">32165498</th>
                <th class="32165498">asdasdasda</th>
                <th class="32165498">
                <input type="button" onclick="editarDatos(this)" value="editar"></th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Y tu script:

```
function editarDatos(e){
    var padreId = e.parentNode.parentNode.id;
    console.log(padreId);
}
```